# How do you render classes dynamically using conditioning on a table on React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I want to change the color of the class depending on the transaction being passed on the table dynamically.

```js
import React from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import "./TableComponent.css";

const TableComponent = ({
  Movement
}) => {
  const colorType = Movement.map((obj) => {
    let colorClass = "p-1 ";
    if (obj.Type === "Deposit") {
      colorClass += "depo";
    } else {
      colorClass += "wit";
    }
    return colorClass;
  });


  const renderMovements = (Movement, i) => {
    return ( <
      tr key = {
        i
      } >
      <
      td className = "p-3" >
      <
      div className = {
        colorType
      } > {
        Movement.Type
      } < /div> <
      /td> <
      td className = "p-3 App"
      colSpan = "2" > {
        Movement.Date
      } <
      /td> <
      td className = "p-3 App" > {
        Movement.Amount
      } < /td> <
      /tr>
    );
  };

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    Table striped bordered hover size = "sm" >
    <
    thead >
    <
    tr >
    <
    th className = "p-2 App" > Transaction < /th> <
    th className = "p-2 App"
    colSpan = "2" >
    Date <
    /th> <
    th className = "p-2 App" > Amount < /th> <
    /tr> <
    /thead> <
    tbody > {
      Movement.map(renderMovements)
    } < /tbody> <
    /Table> <
    button onClick = {
      testColor
    } > Test Color < /button> <
    /div>
  );
};

export default TableComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The problem I have with this is that the last class added would be rendered on each element. When the movement type is a withdrawal I want it to have a red background and if it is a deposit to have a green one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a string from colorType but you are returning a array.

```
  const colorType = (movement) => {
    let colorClass = "p-1 ";
    if (movement.Type === "Deposit") {
      colorClass += "depo";
    } else {
      colorClass += "wit";
    }
    return colorClass;
  });
```

While rendering now you can do this

```
<div className={colorType(Movement)}> 
 {Movement.Type}
</div>
```

Comment: That helped alot!